# Send text strings from Android application/plugin to Unity application

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, snips

I need to add non-Google offline voice control capability to a Unity3D project. I have started with snips.ai and successfully built an Android app following their tutorial and modified it to output the understood intent from snips to a text box on screen. What I really need is to get this text string to send to my Unity application.

I think I should be building a native Android Java plugin for Unity which will start at runtime and listen for voice commands. Every time it gets a listen event I need it to send a string of the captured intent to the Unity project which is always waiting for these strings.

I know I can use something like this https://gist.github.com/markcastle/a1530efd5278607862fec09df89e59db to make a static call to a native plugin, but I want to basically have Unity listening constantly to the plugin for strings which it can interpret.

Any help, as always, is much appreciated!

Comment: I figured out that I needed to import the classes.jar file from the Unity editor. This now allows me to use mUnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage() to send a message to Unity. I have not built this yet or done anything on Unity side yet either. Any guidance from anyone with expertise on this would be massively appreciated!